# Not able to download Jars from nexus

Tags: maven, dependencies, settings, pom.xml, nexus

```
I have project A which is dependency of project B. Since project B should get latest jar version of Project A . I purge Project A jar from local so Project B will get Project A jar from nexus since it has been deleted from local.

I can see in the logs that It can download jar from nexus . but still getting pom for jar is missing

below are the logs


    Downloading from : ://10.245.240.43:8081/nexus/repository/maven-snapshots/com/sgl/smartpra/master/model/smartpra-master-model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/smartpra-master-model-0.0.1-20191126.094645-53.jar
    [INFO] Downloaded from : ://10.245.240.43:8081/nexus/repository/maven-snapshots/com/sgl/smartpra/master/model/smartpra-master-model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/smartpra-master-model-0.0.1-20191126.094645-53.jar (183 kB at 1.7 MB/s)

    The POM for com.sgl.smartpra.master.model:smartpra-master-model:jar:0.0.1-20191126.094645-53 is missing, no dependency information available

You can see that it can able to pull jars from nexus still getting artifact missing.


I added maven plugin to perge dependent jars from local so it will pull latest jar from nexus 
refer Below snippet

    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>purge-local-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>purge-local-repository</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com.sgl.smartpra.global.master.model:smartpra-global-master-model</include>
                                <include>com.sgl.smartpra.batch.global.model:smartpra-batch-global-model</include>
                                <include>com.sgl.smartpra.master.model:smartpra-master-model</include>
                                <include>com.sgl.smartpra.exception.txn.model:smartpra-exception-txn-model</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Below is nexus repository configuration for downloading jars from nexus
Please check below code
refer Below snippet
I have project A which is dependency of project B. Since project B should get latest jar version of Project A . I purge Project A jar from local so Project B will get Project A jar from nexus since it has been deleted from local.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-group</id>
        <url>**strong text**/10.245.240.43:8081/nexus/repository/maven-group/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Pasting the content of pom.XML will help.

Comment: @pmverma  i added pom.xml .

Comment: Why **strong text** instead of http(s)¿